# How to prioritize tables when searching for data in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-optimization

I have a table set up in postgresql database in the following format :

```
GeneTable
Id  GeneSymbol GeneName
```

I am running the following query on the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM GeneTable WHERE GeneSymbol LIKE 'ACR' OR GeneName LIKE 'ACR';
```

I want to prioritize searching the GeneSymbol column first since there is a higher probability that the ACR entity can be found in the GeneSymbol column, which will theoretically help to lower the execution time.  Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` when you are not passing a pattern? Grinds my gears.

Comment: Sorry the title should be "How to prioritize column search in a postgresql table?"

Comment: PostgreSQL should hopefully do that for you using table statistics. See `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) SELECT ...` for details, and also examine the table statistics (see the pg manual).

Comment: Also, you tell RDBMS what to do, not how to do. You can do separate queries.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT *` makes no sense at all. `distinct` applies to **all** columns in the select list. `*` includes the primary key column of the table, thus `distinct` will never remove any duplicates

Comment: @GurwinderSingh using patterns results in longer execution time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - But what if there is no PK/ Unique column?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh: then you have a badly designed table (and the column `id` suggests that there is some kind of unique column)

Comment: Maybe you could use a `CASE` clause to provide some sort of score value.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm just kidding. You're right, of course.

Comment: The id column in the table I mentioned is a foreign key which points to the id primary key in another table.

Comment: I could use subqueries to check one column before another. But I was looking for a more optimized query than using subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

The query optimizer will take care of that. He will estimate selectivity of each expression and select appropriate join. You just need to create indexes to support your queries:

```
 create index ix_genetable_genesymbol on genetable(genesymbol)
 create index ix_genetable_genename on genetable(genename)
```

Please note that searching for all attributes (`SELECT *`) is generally regarded as a [bad habit](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-code-smells/#using-select-in-a-batch). If you really have just three attributes you provide in your question and `id` is a primary key then the following query will run much faster since it will be covered with the above queries:

```
SELECT id FROM GeneTable WHERE GeneSymbol LIKE 'ACR' OR GeneName LIKE 'ACR';
```

Comment: I indexed the columns. The performance still does not seem up to the mark.

Comment: @NiamatZawad are the indexes used by the optimizer? (use EXPLAIN)

Comment: I checked the results and both indexes are used by the optimizer.

Comment: @NiamatZawad: don't use `LIKE` if you don't use patterns. It's much more likely the optimizer will pick the indexes if you use `where genesymbol = 'ACR' or genename = 'ACR'` instead. Using `LIKE` without a pattern makes no sense and just confuses other people that need to understand the query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It does not seems to be a problem, since the indexes are used

Comment: @NiamatZawad could you edit your question and add the query plan?